# Text Manipulator: String position movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, oop, data-structures

The task is to build to a text manipulator: A program that simulates a set of text manipulation commands.Given an input piece of text and a string of commands, output the mutated input text and cursor position.

Starting simple:

Commands

```
 h: move cursor one character to the left
 l: move cursor one character to the right
 r<c>: replace character under cursor with <c>
```

Repeating commands

```
# All commands can be repeated N times by prefixing them with a number.
# 
# [N]h: move cursor N characters to the left
# [N]l: move cursor N characters to the right
# [N]r<c>: replace N characters, starting from the cursor, with <c> and move the cursor
```

Examples

```
# We'll use Hello World as our input text for all cases:
# 
#  Input: hhlhllhlhhll
# Output: Hello World
#           _
#           2
# 
#  Input: rhllllllrw
# Output: hello world
#               _
#               6
# 
#  Input: rh6l9l4hrw
# Output: hello world
#               _
#               6
# 
#  Input: 9lrL7h2rL
# Output: HeLLo WorLd
#            _
#            3
# 
#  Input: 999999999999999999999999999lr0
# Output: Hello Worl0
#                   _
#                  10
# 
#  Input: 999rsom
# Output: sssssssssss
#                   _
#                  10
```

I have written the following piece of code, but getting an error:

```
class Editor():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = 0

    def f(self, step):
        self.pos += int(step)

    def b(self, step):
        self.pos -= int(step)

    def r(self, char):
        s = list(self.text)
        s[self.pos] = char
        self.text = ''.join(s)

    def run(self, command):
        command = list(command)
        # if command not in ('F','B', 'R'):
        #
        while command:
            operation = command.pop(0).lower()
            if operation not in ('f','b','r'):
                raise ValueError('command not recognized.')
            method = getattr(self, operation)
            arg = command.pop(0)
            method(arg)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

# Normal run
text = 'abcdefghijklmn'
command = 'F2B1F5Rw'

ed = Editor(text)
ed.run(command)
print(ed)
```

I have used 'F' and 'B' in my code instead of 'h' and 'l', but the problem is I am missing a piece that allows me to define the optional 'N'. My code only works if there is a number defined after an operation.
How can I fix the code above to meet all the requirements?

Comment: You need to process the input as a simple state machine.  When in the state where you're waiting for an operation, you can accept either a digit or a character.  If a digit arrives, you store it and continue collecting digits until you receive a non-digit.  At that point, you can then determine the number of repeats requested and then run your operation.  If no digit arrives before a command, then the number of repeats is 1.

Comment: Interesting, but that's a bit complicated to wrap my head around. Can you share some code?

Comment: Spend more time wrapping your head around it.  This is about as simple as text parsing gets.  Write down a command string on paper, then walk through with your finger, pointing at each character in turn.  For each character, decide if you have enough information to execute an operation yet.  If not, write down anything you need to remember before moving to the next character.  If it's ready to execute, use the stuff you wrote down to determine what action to take.  Continue like this until you reach the end of the string.  If you can work through this on paper, you can turn it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem is figuring out how to parse the command string. From your description, the command string contains an optional number, followed by either of the following three possibilities:

- `h`
- `l`
- `r`, followed by a character

A regex to parse this would be ([try online](https://regex101.com/r/lQfyGa/1)):

```
(\d*)(h|l|r.)

Explanation:

(\d*)            Capture zero or more digits, 
     (h|l|r.)    Capture either an h, or an l, or an r followed by any character
```

Using `re.findall()` with this regex, you can get a list of matches, where each match is a `tuple` containing the captured groups. For example, `"rh6l9l4hrw"` gives the result

```
[('', 'rh'), ('6', 'l'), ('9', 'l'), ('4', 'h'), ('', 'rw')]
```

So the first element of the tuple is a string representing `N` (or an empty string if none exists), and the second element of the tuple is the command. If the command is `r`, it will contain the replacement character after it. Now all we need to do is iterate over this list, and apply the correct commands.

I made a few changes:

1. Access `self.pos` through a property with a setter that handles the correct bounds checking
2. explode the input text into a list when the object is created, because it's not possible to modify strings in-place like you can with a list. `__str__()` joins the list back to a string.
3. Access `self.text` through a readonly property, which joins the `self.__text` list into a string.

```
class Editor():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.__text = [char for char in text]
        self.__pos = 0
    
    @property
    def text(self):
        return "".join(self.__text)
    
    @property
    def pos(self):
        return self.__pos
    
    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, value):
        self.__pos = max(0, min(len(self.text)-1, value))

    def l(self, step):
        self.pos = self.pos + step

    def h(self, step):
        self.pos = self.pos - step

    def r(self, char, count=1):
        # If count causes the cursor to overshoot the text, 
        # modify count
        count = min(count, len(self.__text) - self.pos)
        self.__text[self.pos:self.pos+count] = char * count
        self.pos = self.pos + count - 1 # Set position to last replaced character

    def run(self, command):
        commands = re.findall(r"(\d*)(h|l|r.)", command)
        
        for cmd in commands:
            self.validate(cmd)
            count = int(cmd[0] or "1") # If cmd[0] is blank, use count = 1
            if cmd[1] == "h":
                self.h(count)
            elif cmd[1] == "l":
                self.l(count)
            elif cmd[1][0] == "r":
                self.r(cmd[1][1], count)

    def validate(self, cmd):
        cmd_s = ''.join(cmd)
        if cmd[0] and not cmd[0].isnumeric():
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid numeric input {cmd[0]} for command {cmd_s}")
        elif cmd[1][0] not in "hlr":
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid command {cmd_s}: Must be either h or l or r")
        elif cmd[1] == 'r' and len(cmd) == 1:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid command {cmd_s}: r command needs an argument")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Running this with your given inputs:

```
commands = ["hhlhllhlhhll", "rhllllllrw", "rh6l9l4hrw", "9lrL7h2rL", "999999999999999999999999999lr0", "999rsom"]

for cmd in commands:
    e = Editor("Hello World")
    e.run(cmd)
    uline = "        " + " " * e.pos + "^"
    cline = "Cursor: " + " " * e.pos + str(e.pos)
    print(f"Input: {cmd}\nOutput: {str(e)}\n{uline}\n{cline}\n")
```

```
Input: hhlhllhlhhll
Output: Hello World
          ^
Cursor:   2

Input: rhllllllrw
Output: hello world
              ^
Cursor:       6

Input: rh6l9l4hrw
Output: hello world
              ^
Cursor:       6

Input: 9lrL7h2rL
Output: HeLLo WorLd
           ^
Cursor:    3

Input: 999999999999999999999999999lr0
Output: Hello Worl0
                  ^
Cursor:           10

Input: 999rsom
Output: sssssssssss
                  ^
Cursor:           10
```

---

Now, if you want to do the same without regex, you just gotta figure out a way to parse the input command string into that kind of a list of tuples and you can use the same logic as before to do the actual replacement.

Here, I'm going to do this by writing a function that takes a string, and returns an iterator over all the commands in it. Each element yielded will be a single tuple that looks like an element of the list returned by `re.findall()`. This will allow us to simply replace the call to `re.findall()` with our custom parser:

```
    def iter_command(self, command: str):
        cmd = [[], []]
        # The command is made of two segments: 
        # 1. The number part
        # 2. The letters "h|l|r." part of the regex
        seg = 0 # Start with the first segment
        for cpos, char in enumerate(command):
            if seg == 0:
                if "0" <= char <= "9":
                    # If the character is a number, append it to the first segment
                    cmd[seg].append(char)
                elif char in "hlr":
                    # Else, if the character is h or l or r, move on to the next segment
                    seg = 1
                    
            if seg == 1:
                if not cmd[seg] and char in "hlr":
                    # If this segment is empty and the character is h|l|r
                    cmd[seg] = [char] 
                    if char != "r":
                        # Convert our list of lists of characters to a tuple of strings and yield it
                        yield tuple(''.join(l) for l in cmd)
                        # Then reset cmd and seg to process the next command
                        cmd = [[], []]
                        seg = 0
                    else: # char == r
                        pass # So do one more iteration
                elif cmd[seg] and cmd[seg][-1] == "r": # Command is r, so listening for any character
                    cmd[seg].append(char)
                    # Same yield tasks as before
                    yield tuple(''.join(l) for l in cmd)
                    cmd = [[], []]
                    seg = 0
                else: # This is a character we don't care about
                # So do nothing with it
                    if any(cmd):
                        yield tuple(''.join(l) for l in cmd)
                    cmd = [[], []]
                    seg = 0
```

Now, let's test this against the regex from before:

```
commands = ["hhlhllhlhhll", "rhllllllrw", "rh6l9l4hrw", "9lrL7h2rL", "999999999999999999999999999lr0", "999rsom"]

for cmd in commands:
    e = Editor("Hello World")
    commands_custom = list(e.iter_command(cmd))
    commands_regex = re.findall(r"(\d*)(h|l|r.)", cmd)
    
    print(commands_custom)
    print(commands_regex)
    print(cmd)
    print(all(a == b for a, b in zip(commands_custom, commands_regex)))
    print("")
```

```
[('', 'h'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l')]
[('', 'h'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'h'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l')]
hhlhllhlhhll
True

[('', 'rh'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'rw')]
[('', 'rh'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'l'), ('', 'rw')]
rhllllllrw
True

[('', 'rh'), ('6', 'l'), ('9', 'l'), ('4', 'h'), ('', 'rw')]
[('', 'rh'), ('6', 'l'), ('9', 'l'), ('4', 'h'), ('', 'rw')]
rh6l9l4hrw
True

[('9', 'l'), ('', 'rL'), ('7', 'h'), ('2', 'rL')]
[('9', 'l'), ('', 'rL'), ('7', 'h'), ('2', 'rL')]
9lrL7h2rL
True

[('999999999999999999999999999', 'l'), ('', 'r0')]
[('999999999999999999999999999', 'l'), ('', 'r0')]
999999999999999999999999999lr0
True

[('999', 'rs')]
[('999', 'rs')]
999rsom
True
```

And, since these give identical results, we just need to replace the call to `re.findall()`:

```
    def run(self, command):
-        commands = re.findall(r"(\d*)(h|l|r.)", command)
+        commands = self.iter_command(command)

        for cmd in commands:
```

Comment: Wondering if there a way to do this without regex?

Comment: @coderWorld Sure there is! You just gotta figure out how to convert your command to that kind of list of tuples, and then the same logic applies. I'll write some code to demonstrate shortly.

Comment: @coderWorld I edited my answer to demonstrate how to parse the input command

Answer (score 1):

@paddy gave you a good advice, but looking at the string you need to parse, it seems to me that a regular expression would do the job quite easily. For the part after parsing, a [Command pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command) fits pretty well. Afterall you have a list of operations (*commands*) that must be executed over an initial string.

In your case using this pattern brings mainly 3 advantages in my opinion:

- Each `Command` represents an operation applied to the initial string. This also means that, for example, in case you want to add a shortcut for a sequence of operations, the number of final `Command`s stays the same and you only have to adjust the parsing step. Another benefit is that you can have a history of commands and in general the design is much more flexible.
- All `Command`s share a common interface: a method `execute()` and, if necessary, a method `unexecute()` to undo the changes applied by the `execute()` method.
- `Command`s decouple the operations execution from the parsing problem.

---

As for the implementation, first you define `Command`s, that do not contain any business logic except for the call to the receiver method.

```
from __future__ import annotations
import functools
import re
import abc
from typing import Iterable

class ICommand(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, target: TextManipulator):
        self._target = target

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass

class MoveCursorLeftCommand(ICommand):
    def __init__(self, target: TextManipulator, counter):
        super().__init__(target)
        self._counter = counter

    def execute(self):
        self._target.move_cursor_left(self._counter)

class MoveCursorRightCommand(ICommand):
    def __init__(self, target: TextManipulator, counter):
        super().__init__(target)
        self._counter = counter

    def execute(self):
        self._target.move_cursor_right(self._counter)

class ReplaceCommand(ICommand):
    def __init__(self, target: TextManipulator, counter, replacement):
        super().__init__(target)
        self._replacement = replacement
        self._counter = counter

    def execute(self):
        self._target.replace_char(self._counter, self._replacement)
```

---

Then you have the receiver of commands, which is the `TextManipulator` and contains methods to change the text and the cursor position.

```
class TextManipulator:
    """
    >>> def apply_commands(s, commands_str): 
    ...     return TextManipulator(s).run_commands(CommandParser.parse(commands_str))
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', 'hhlhllhlhhll')
    ('Hello World', 2)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', 'rhllllllrw')
    ('hello world', 6)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', 'rh6l9l4hrw')
    ('hello world', 6)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', '9lrL7h2rL')
    ('HeLLo WorLd', 3)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', '999999999999999999999999999lr0')
    ('Hello Worl0', 10)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', '999rsom')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: command 'o' not recognized.
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', '7l5r1')
    ('Hello W1111', 10)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', '7l4r1')
    ('Hello W1111', 10)
    >>> apply_commands('Hello World', '7l3r1')
    ('Hello W111d', 9)
    """
    def __init__(self, text):
        self._text = text
        self._cursor_pos = 0

    def replace_char(self, counter, replacement):
        assert len(replacement) == 1
        assert counter >= 0
        self._text = self._text[0:self._cursor_pos] + \
            replacement * min(counter, len(self._text) - self._cursor_pos) + \
            self._text[self._cursor_pos + counter:]

        self.move_cursor_right(counter - 1)

    def move_cursor_left(self, counter):
        assert counter >= 0
        self._cursor_pos = max(0, self._cursor_pos - counter)

    def move_cursor_right(self, counter):
        assert counter >= 0
        self._cursor_pos = min(len(self._text) - 1, self._cursor_pos + counter)

    def run_commands(self, commands: Iterable[ICommand]):
        for cmd in map(lambda partial_cmd: partial_cmd(target=self), commands):
            cmd.execute()

        return (self._text, self._cursor_pos)
```

Nothing really hard to explain about this code except for the `run_commands` method, that accepts an iterable of partial commands. These partial commands are commands that have been initiated without the receiver object, that should be of type `TextManipulator`. Why should you do that? It is a possible way to decouple parsing from commands execution. I decided to do it with `functools.partial` but you have other valid options.

---

Eventually, the parsing part:

```
class CommandParser:
    @staticmethod
    def parse(commands_str: str):
        def invalid_command(match: re.Match):
            raise ValueError(f"command '{match.group(2)}' not recognized.")

        get_counter_from_match = lambda m: int(m.group(1) or 1)
        commands_map = { 
            'h': lambda match: functools.partial(MoveCursorLeftCommand, \
                counter=get_counter_from_match(match)), 
            'l': lambda match: functools.partial(MoveCursorRightCommand, \
                counter=get_counter_from_match(match)), 
            'r': lambda match: functools.partial(ReplaceCommand, \
                counter=get_counter_from_match(match), replacement=match.group(3))
        }
        parsed_commands_iter = re.finditer(r'(\d*)(h|l|r(\w)|.)', commands_str)
        commands = map(lambda match: \
            commands_map.get(match.group(2)[0], invalid_command)(match), parsed_commands_iter)
        
        return commands

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

As I said at the beginning, parsing can be done with regex in your case and command creation is based on the first letter of the second capturing group of each match. The reason is that for the char replacement, the second capturing group includes the char to be replaced too. The `commands_map` is accessed with `match.group(2)[0]` as key and return a partial `Command`. If the operation is not found in the map, it throws a `ValueError` exception. The parameters of each `Command` are inferred from the `re.Match` object.

---

Just put all these code snippet together and you have a working solution (and some tests provided by the docstring executed by `doctest`).

This could be an over complicated design in some scenarios, so I am not saying that is the correct way to do it (it is probably not if you are writing a simple tool for example). You can avoid the `Command`s part and just take the parsing solution, but I have found this to be an interesting  (alternative) application of the pattern.